# Mostrando valores de modelos relacionados dentro de una plantilla

Tags: python, django

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual debo de mostrar las información de un paciente en una plantilla. Para este proceso estoy usando una `DetailView`, con un modelo de `Paciente`, a este modelo `Paciente` están relacionadas otros modelos, tales como la de la información acerca del `Seguro`, `Antecedentes Médicos`, `Parientes`, etc y me gustaría usar esta información para mostrarla también en mi plantilla, pero no logro conseguirlo.

He estado reescribiendo el método de `Get_context_data`, pero no logro mostrar ningún valor en la plantilla, abajo les dejare mi código, soy nuevo en esto y soy abierto a recomendaciones en cuanto a mi código o mejores practicas.

Como pueden ver, el ultimo campo de todos los modelos que no son `Patient`, están relacionados a `Patient` mediante una llave foránea, es la información de estos modelos la que me gustaría mostrar en mi plantilla.

## Modelos

```
class Allergies(models.Model):
    Alergia = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Allergie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Alergia

class Patient(models.Model):
    Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None,null=False)
    Nombres = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    Fecha_Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    Numero_Telefonico = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=' ')
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True,blank=True,default=' ')
    Genero = models.ForeignKey(Gender,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Nacionalidad = models.ForeignKey(Nationality,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Estado_Civil = models.ForeignKey(CivilStatus,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True)
    Ocupacion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Lugar_de_Procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Lugar_de_Residencia = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombres + ' ' + self.Apellidos

class MedicalInfo(models.Model):
    Expediente = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Sangre = models.ForeignKey(BloodType,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,null=True)
    Peso = models.FloatField()
    Estatura = models.FloatField()
    Alergia = models.ForeignKey(Allergies,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    Observacion = models.CharField(max_length=500,default= ' ',null=True,blank=True)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)


class InsuranceInfo(models.Model):
    Seguro = models.ForeignKey(InsuranceCompany,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Tipo_de_Poliza = models.ForeignKey(Policy,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Numero_Poliza = models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Vencimiento = models.DateField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)


class Relatives(models.Model):
    Parentesco = models.ForeignKey(Family_relation, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Correo = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    Nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Pariente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Relative'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombre + ' ' + self.Apellido

class Background(models.Model):
    Padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    Control = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    Medicamento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Paciente = models.OneToOneField(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
```

Aquí les muestro mi intento por mostrar la información de seguros:

## Views

```
class PatientsDetail(DetailView):
    model = Patient
    template_name = 'patients/patient_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PatientsDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['insurance'] = InsuranceInfo.objects.filter(Paciente=self.get_object())
        return context
```

## Mi Plantilla

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load staticfiles%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'patients/css/patient_details.css'%}">
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>Datos del Paciente: {{patient.Nombres}}</h3>
    <p>ID: {{patient.Codigo}}</p>
    <p>Nombre: {{patient.Nombres}}</p>
    <p>Apellido: {{patient.Apellidos}}</p>
    <p>Fecha de Nacimiento: {{patient.Fecha_Nacimiento}}</p>
    <p>Telefono: {{patient.Numero_Telefonico}}</p>
    <p>Correo: {{patient.Email}}</p>
    <p>Genero: {{patient.Genero}}</p>
    <p>Nacionalidad: {{patient.Nacionalidad}}</p>
    <p>Estado Civil: {{patient.Estado_Civil}}</p>
    <p>Ocupacion: {{patient.Ocupacion}}</p>
    <p>Procedencia: {{patient.Lugar_de_Procedencia}}</p>
    <p>Residencia: {{patient.Lugar_de_Residencia}}</p>
    <p>Seguro : {{insurance.Seguro}}</p>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Según entiendo quieres mostrar las instancias relacionadas a una instancia especifica del modelo `Patient` que serian instancias de los modelos `MedicalInfo`, `InsuranceInfo`, `Relatives` y `Background` verdad?

Comment: Correcto, quisiera mostrar la informacion de InsuranceInfo relacionada a ese Patient en mi plantilla!

Comment: Solo del modelo `InsuranceInfo`?

Comment: Sería la de MedicalInfo, InsuranceInfo, Relatives y Background, pero sería el mismo procedimiento para todas las demás, sugerí InsuranceInfo para guiarme y completar los otros 3 modelos!

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para acceder a una instancia relacionada al modelo `Patient`, seria asi:

```
>>> p = Patient.objects.get(...)
>>> p.nombre_del_modelo_relacionado
<ModelName: ...>
```

Es decir para acceder a la instancia relacionada del modelo `Background` por ejemplo, seria así:

```
>>> p.background
<Background: ...>
```

Recuerda que `p.background` es una instancia es decir puedes acceder a los atributos de dicha instancia:

```
>>> p.background.Padecimiento
...
>>> p.background.Medicamento
...
```

Así seria con todos los modelos **que tengan una relación uno a uno (`OneToOneField`) con el modelo `Patient`**. Con las demás relaciones (`ManyToManyField`, etc) las cosas cambian.

Entonces en tu template deberías mostrar los datos de las instancias relacionadas, algo así:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    ...

    <h3>Background</h3>
    <p>Instancia relacionada: {{ patient.background }}</p>
    <p>Atributo "Padecimiento" de la instancia relacionada: {{ patient.background.Padecimiento }}</p>
    <!-- y asi sucesivamente ya sea con las demas instancias relacionadas o con los atributos -->
    ...
</div>
```

Mas detalles en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) sobre las relaciones uno a uno.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Wow! deberas que aplique todo lo que me has dicho en mi proyecto y ya esta funcionando de maravilla, todos los valores se estan mostrando sin ningun problema, pero tengo una ultima pregunta @Julio Cesar, yo habia buscado informacion aqui antes de realizar la pregunta, y lei que tenia que sobreecribir el metodo de get_context_data, al final esto no es necesario?

Comment: Claro que no, el método `get_context_data` es para extender el contexto que se le pasara al template y por defecto la vista `DetailView` ya pasa en el contexto del template la instancia obtenida, es por eso que puedes acceder a las instancias relacionadas y a sus respectivos atributos.

Comment: Comprendo, excelente saber eso! Muchisimas gracias Julio Cesar por tu tiempo y por brindarme una solucion, te lo agradezco muchisimo!

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! Por cierto por convención solo los nombres de clase empiezan con mayúsculas no las variables ni atributos, es decir los nombres de clase deberían ser así: "MiClase" y los nombres de funciones, variables, atributos, etc, así: "mi_funcion", "mi_variable", etc. Te recomiendo seguir las convenciones pues son de buena practica :)